# How temperature difference does not affect transistors in CPUs?

Tags: transistors, semiconductors, cpu, nmos, pn-junction

Recently I learned about semi-conductors and some devices.
Today I watched a video on youtube about a guy overclocking a cpu to 7.0 ghz, while cooling it with liquid nitrogen to -192 celsius degrees. This range of temperatures is vast and iam having a difficulty to understand how the silicon does not reach freeze out zone and does not act like an insulator, or when reaching high temperatures (for example in gaming) the thermal generation does not mess things up and crash the whole system.
For example if the thermal generation was high on a ( in a MOS transistor) will it cause free charges to pass through the pipe and turn it from 0 to 1 even though we are still in low voltage (V gate < V threshold) ..?

How do they overcome those things?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: He may have cooled it with fluid that cold, but I'm guessing the actual die temperature was much higher.

Comment: Was he submerging it in liquid nitrogen or releasing it in in controlled amounts so it vapourized and cooled the surrounding air rather than making direct contact? Because if I spray you with ice water your body temperature doesn't immediately drop to 0C, but if I submerge you in ice water you will freeze very quickly. There may also be a vapour film/blanket preventing the liquid from making direction contact (look up quenching steel in water). It may not be possible to sustain this vapour blanket evenly for long periods of time though.

Comment: https://youtu.be/WwJvHJ1hyto this is the link of the video on youtube